# Python: Using dict as accumulator

Tags: python

I am trying to get the counts of each word in a text file with the below code.

```
def count_words(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f: return reduce(lambda acc, x: acc.get(x, 0) + 1,   sum([line.split() for line in f], []), dict())
```

but I get the error

```
File "C:\Python27\abc.py", line 173, in count_words
with open(file_name, 'r') as f: return reduce(lambda acc, x: acc.get(x, 0) + 1, sum([line.split() for line in f], []), dict())
File "C:\Python27\abc.py", line 173, in <lambda>
with open(file_name, 'r') as f: return reduce(lambda acc, x: acc.get(x, 0) + 1, sum([line.split() for line in f], []), dict())
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I am not able to understand the error message here. Why does it complain that 'int' has no attribute even when I passed a dict as accumulator?

Comment: I have replaced the reduce call above with collections.Counter and it worked for me

Answer (score 3):

You can use `collections.Counter` to count the words:

```
In [692]: t='I am trying to get the counts of each word in a text file with the below code'
In [693]: from collections import Counter

In [694]: Counter(t.split())
Out[694]: Counter({'the': 2, 'a': 1, 'code': 1, 'word': 1, 'get': 1, 'I': 1, 'of': 1, 'in': 1, 'am': 1, 'to': 1, 'below': 1, 'text': 1, 'file': 1, 'each': 1, 'trying': 1, 'with': 1, 'counts': 1})

In [695]: c=Counter(t.split())

In [696]: c['the']
Out[696]: 2
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your lambda function returns an `int`, but not a `dict`.

So, even if you use a `dict` as seed, when your lambda function is called the second time, `acc` will be the result of `acc.get(x, 0) + 1` from the first call, and it's an `int` and not a `dict`.

Comment: Got it, Thanks! Is there any way to fix the reduce call above? I have managed to fix by calling a helper function increment which increments the word count and returns the dict but I am looking for a single line solution

Comment: Using a helper method is the way to go here if you really want to use reduce. But the better way is to simply use a `Counter`. It's there for making counting things easy.

Answer (score 1):

So if you are looking for a one-liner, I almost have a one-liner in the spirit of what you were trying to do with get.

```
>>> words = """One flew over the ocean
... One flew over the sea
... My Bonnie loves pizza
... but she doesn't love me"""
>>>
>>> f = open('foo.txt', 'w')
>>> f.writelines(words)
>>> f.close()
```

The "one-liner" (two-liner actually)

```
>>> word_count = {}
>>> with open('foo.txt', 'r') as f:
...     _ = [word_count.update({word:word_count.get(word,0)+1}) for word in f.read().split()]
...
```

Result:

```
>>> word_count
{'but': 1, 'One': 2, 'the': 2, 'she': 1, 'over': 2, 'love': 1, 'loves': 1, 'ocean': 1, "doesn't": 1, 'pizza': 1, 'My': 1, 'me': 1, 'flew': 2, 'sea': 1, 'Bonnie': 1}
```

I imagine there's something you could do with a dict comprehension, but I couldn't see how to use `get` in that case.

The `f.read().split()` gives you a nice list of words to work with, however, and should be easier than trying to get words out of a list of lines.  It's a better approach unless you have a huge file.